# mmap file with larger fixed length with zero padding?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I want to use `mmap()` to read a file with fixed length (eg. 64MB), but there also some files < 64MB.

I mmap this files (<64MB, eg.30MB) with length = 64MB, when read file data beyond file size(30MB - 64MB), the program got a `bus-error`.

I want mmap these files with fixed length, and read 0x00 when pointer beyond file size. How to do that?

One method I can think is `ftruncate` file first, and `ftruncate` back to ori size, but I don't think this method is perfect.

Comment: Are you saying that you're reading a file, and then writing it to another 64MB file? Or just reading from a file, and allocating 64MB to it? If it's the latter, then I think you're handling the memory wrong from a higher level, you shouldn't need zeroes past the file size (Just have a variable for the size).

Comment: @NicholasPipitone hi，actually I am using a group of 64MB blocks to generate erasure coding blocks

Comment: Is your question really relevant to both C and C++? Just because C++ is based on C doesn't make the C tag relevant in a C++ question or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the few reasonable use cases for `MAP_FIXED`, to remap part of an existing mapping to use a new backing file.

A simple solution here is to unconditionally `mmap` 64 MB of anonymous memory (or explicitly mmap `/dev/zero`),  *without* `MAP_FIXED` and store the resulting pointer.

Next, `mmap` 64 MB or your actual file size (whichever is less) of your actual file, passing in the result of the anonymous/zero `mmap` and passing the `MAP_FIXED` flag. The pages corresponding to your file will no longer be anonymous/zero mapped, and instead will be backed by your file's data; the remaining pages will be backed by the anonymous/zero pages.

When you're done, a single `munmap` call will unmap all 64 MB at once (you don't need to separately unmap the real file pages and the zero backed pages).

Extremely simple example (no error checking, please add it yourself):

```
// Reserve 64 MB of contiguous addresses; anonymous mappings are always zero backed
void *mapping = mmap(NULL, 64 * 1024 * 1024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

// Open file and check size
struct stat sb;
int fd = open(myfilename, O_RDONLY);
fstat(fd, &sb);
// Use smaller of file size or 64 MB
size_t filemapsize = sb.st_size > 64 * 1024 * 1024 ? 64 * 1024 * 1024 : sb.st_size;
// Remap up to 64 MB of pages, replacing some or all of original anonymous pages
mapping = mmap(mapping, filemapsize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
close(fd);

// ... do stuff with mapping ...
munmap(mapping, 64 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Comment: I did not know you could do this.. I don't need it, I was just reading out of curiosity.. but this is kind of neat :).

Comment: @Rob: I discovered it when I was trying to do something much more complicated; map in a few thousand files (all a multiple of the page size) as if they were a single contiguous block of data in memory. I could have just `malloc`ed and read in each file one by one, but the data sizes I was dealing with were huge, and reads were random, so spending a minute or more populating a buffer was a pain; mapping a single block equal to the combined file sizes, then performing a per-file remap using `MAP_FIXED` to map each file immediately after the last, saved over a minute of disk I/O at startup.

Comment: The other advantage to `mmap`ing in that case was when the system came under memory pressure; if I'd `malloc`ed a buffer and populated it via `read`s, when the system was under RAM pressure and the OS needed to swap, it would have to write the `malloc`ed pages to the swap file (at a time when it's definitionally under load, and disk I/O is at a premium). With read-only shared maps of the original files, it can just drop the pages without writing anything, reloading from disk later if the data is needed.

Comment: I second the comment by @Rob.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have used mmap many times before :) just not the mapping of one file over another, and definitely never though of the /dev/zero trick with anonymous maps I never tried it I always had a HUGE file or another so it never occurred to me:) love it.